# java dateformat with oracle format gives ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: sql, oracle

The date field in oracle DB is stored in '10-FEB-99' format. My calander function in UI accepts date in this format '02/30/2023'.
When i search date in UI, i have to query the DB with date field from UI to what exists in DB.

```
select * from case where TO_CHAR(p.OCCASION_FROM_DATE,'dd-MON-yyyy') = TO_CHAR('02/10/1999','MM/dd/yyyy');
```

When I execute this query I get below exception

**ORA-01722: invalid number
00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.**

Tried this

select * from case where TO_CHAR(p.OCCASION_FROM_DATE,'dd-MON-yyyy') = TO_CHAR('02/10/1999','MM/dd/yyyy');

Comment: What do you expect `TO_CHAR('02/10/1999','MM/dd/yyyy')` to return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The date field in oracle DB is stored in '10-FEB-99' format.

Is it? Perhaps. It depends on column **datatype**. What is it? If it is `VARCHAR2`, then yes - it might be stored that way, and that's *wrong*. You should always store dates into `DATE` datatype columns.

Let's presume it is a `varchar2` column. In that case, you should match two values: first convert a string (`02/10/1999`) to a valid date value (using `to_date` with appropriate format model), and then back to string - again with format model that matches string stored into the column:

```
select * from case p 
where p.OCCASION_FROM_DATE = 
      to_char(to_date('02/10/1999','MM/dd/yyyy'), 'dd-mon-rr', 'nls_date_language = english);
```

---

On the other hand, if values stored in table are in `date` datatype column (yes, that should be the case!), note that dates aren't stored in human-readable format. That's a 7-byte value representing century/year/month/day/hour/minute/second. The fact that you *see* it as `10-feb-99` is because your current NLS settings say so.

Query then gets somewhat simpler because you just have to *convert* string `02/10/1999` to date:

```
select * from case p
where p.occasion_from_date = to_date('02/10/1999', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```